# Ruby + Curses: Non-blocking getch() + Trap for Ctrl+c?

Tags: ruby, curses

I want to use Curses in Ruby:

1. `getch()` cannot block/suspend the program.
2. When pressing `q` , exit the program **immediately**.
3. A trap for `Ctrl-C` to avoid interruption.

However, I just can done the first point:

2. When press `q`, it would wait for a while (< 1 sec) before exit.
3. It seems that `Curses` makes the *trap for `Ctrl-C`* not work at all...

```rb
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
require "curses"

Curses.init_screen
Curses.noecho()
Curses.curs_set(0)              #invisible cursor
Curses.timeout = 0
Curses.addstr("Press [q] to abort")
sec=0
while true

  # if place this outside the while loop, q key will be unable to work
  # at all...
  if Curses.getch == 'q'
    Curses.close_screen         #seems unnecessary
    exit
  end

  sec += 1
  hello = "Hello World #{sec}"
  Curses.setpos(Curses.lines / 2, Curses.cols / 2 - (hello.length / 2))
  Curses.addstr(hello)
  Curses.refresh
  sleep 1
end

# Avoid C-c interruption, but Curses seems to ignore it.
Signal.trap(:INT){
  return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When press q, it would wait for a while (< 1 sec) before exit.

You should combine unresponsive sleep with blocking input:
Set `timeout = 1000` and remove `sleep 1`.

If this is not what you want, then you need multithreading.

> A trap for Ctrl-C to avoid interruption.

You can use `Curses.raw()` to switch to raw mode, where all input will be transfered to you directly, without automatic handling of Ctrl+C and such.